# Rotate whole HTML including touch input javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I'm currently working on a touch device (non-mobile). 
It is kind of a table with a touchscreen in it and build in html/js/css.

I build a button that would rotate the whole page 180 degrees. So that you can pass control to someone on the other side of the table.

```js
$(function(){
  var rotation = 0;
  $( ".rotate" ).click(function() {
    rotation = rotation + 180;
    //alert(rotation);
      $("html").css("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");  
  });
});
```

It works fine but the touch input is inverted afterwards, because it doesn't seem to rotate. Is there any way to rotate it as well?

for example: it uses the google maps api. When I navigate right from it scrolls the wrong way.

Comment: not sure if rotating the WHOLE html is the way to go. You need to probably re-think the requirement and rotate only the needed elements

Comment: I wouldn't mind rotating just certain elements, but than the problem most likely will remain. That input will be inverted on that object. So far example i want to rotate the google maps api than the touch input would definetly be inverted.

Comment: So i've tried to only for example rotate the iframe that holds the google maps api. Same problem i can visually rotate the iframe but i cant make the browser orient it 180degrees so it will correctly use touch input.